Tikz for CPU operation drawing/schematic
My aim is to visualize an ALU operation like this:

What I have so far is:

\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, scopes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=0mm,
  font=\sffamily
]
\tikzset{N/.style={draw, fill=green!20,inner sep=4pt}}
\begin{scope}[start chain=D going below,
  nodes={on chain=D},
  ]%
  \foreach \r in {0,1,...,4}{
      \node[N] {Data \r};
  }
\end{scope}
\node[above] at (D-1.north west) {\footnotesize MSB};
\node[above] at (D-1.north east) {\footnotesize LSB};
\end{tikzpicture}

\ctikzset{muxdemuxes/fill=cyan!20}

\begin{circuitikz}[
    font=\sffamily,
  ]
  \node [muxdemux, muxdemux def={
    Lh=6, Rh=2, w=2,
    inset Lh=2, inset Rh=0, inset w=1,
    NL=4, NR=2, NT=0, NB=0,
  }](ALU) at (0,0) {\rotatebox{0}{$\pm$}};
  \node[above] at (ALU.lpin 1) {A};
  \node[draw=none] at (ALU.lpin 2) {}; % TBD prevent from drawing
  \node[above] at (ALU.lpin 3) {B};
  \node[above] at (ALU.lpin 4) {carry in};
  \node[above] at (ALU.rpin 1) {carry out};
  \node[above] at (ALU.rpin 2) {C};
\end{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\bitrect}[2]{
    \draw [thick] (0,0) rectangle (#1*0.7,0.7*1);
    % draw ticks for bit labels
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bitwidth{#1-1}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\bitwidth}
      \draw (\x*0.7,0.5) -- (\x*0.7, 0.7);
  \bitlabels{#1}{#2}
}
\newcommand{\psw}[3]{
  \draw (#1*0.7,0) rectangle ++(#2*0.7,1*0.7) node[pos=0.5]{#3};
}
\newcommand{\pswX}[3]{
 \draw [thick, fill=blue!20] (#1*0.7,0) rectangle ++(#2*0.7,1*0.7) node[pos=0.5]{#3};
}
\newcommand{\bitlabels}[2]{
  \foreach \bit in {1,...,#1}{
     \pgfmathsetmacro\bitnumber{#2}
     \node [above] at (0.7*\bit-0.7*0.5, 1*0.7) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\bitnumber}};
   }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=B going right]
  \node[draw, on chain=B, fill=yellow!80] (PSW){APSW};
  \begin{scope}[xshift=7mm, on chain=B]
    \bitrect{32}{32-\bit} % {length}{index label expression}
    \psw{0}{1}{N}    % {start bit}{length}{label}
    \psw{1}{1}{Z}
    \pswX{2}{1}{C}
    \psw{3}{1}{V}
    \psw{4}{1}{Q}
    \psw{4}{5}{XX}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

As you can, a lot of work still there. One of the bigger problem is to connect all the components used here. The register stack on the left side is as expected so far.
My ALU drawing source has the problem of count of pins on the top left side (where is A is the only pin). Using 3 pins on the left places the 2nd in the middle of the ALU/muxdemux which isn't intended (maybe a limitation by circuitikz?).
I tried to make the bit boxes on the right side a bit narrower (by 70%), but that doesn't really work and makes the LaTeX source very unclear. As a reference, I took the solution from Draw register map with TikZ and adapted it to my problem.
To the left of the bit box is the name of this register, and it should be 1pt next to it at the same height (it represents exactly this register content). The height of this register should be the same as the individual fields of the register stack on the far left, so the bit box should also have exactly the same height. The identifiers within the bit box must also be centered - I somehow lost this during the 70% scaling. Another challenge of the bit box is the interruption, displaying more bits does not make sense and makes the image unnecessarily wide (as can also be seen in my design).
Edit:
As the comments suggested, I've separated one of my concerns to an own question: Compact register map with TikZ and will update this question later on.

That's a lot of questions for a single question .... Could you also edit your question to include the colours of things (unless you are colour blind)? Is the 'bit box' the orange thing or the green one or what? That would make it easier for people outside your discipline to help,

Hi, welcome! I think you should split this question as suggested by @cfr. Try for example one question for the ALU pins (I can answer that), another for the bit box, etc...

I actually started trying to figure this out, but, frankly, I abandoned the attempt. I spent a bit of time and I still wasn't even sure which bit the 'bit box' was or what the various bits of code were doing. I stopped the proliferation of 32 boxes and started to sort out the 0.7 thing. The solution to that is easy. It's figuring out where to apply it in your code which is tricky. I couldn't figure out why so many commands or what they were for. Unlike @Rmano, I didn't even attempt the pins. If I can't figure out the rest, that part's never going to happen :(. The boxes should be easy ....

UPDATE
Adding some corrections as indicated by Rmano, I don't know why I didn't consider if it was visible in the manual page 138 which I reviewed the first time from CTAN ...Whatever I added some tuning in terms of the styles so that it matches the boxes defined using draw, for style N the value of inner sep a 4.25pt, then to avoid repeating the styles of the arrow texts, create a new style with the variable in inner sep. Finally, to add the space between the first node 0, I added a variable that depends on the iteration of the counter t, if it is zero, the separation is 2pt and if it is not 0pt, that way I obtain the separation that is required.
Update Result:

Update MWE:
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes,positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        font=\sffamily,
        >={Triangle},
        N/.style={
            draw,
            fill=green!20,
            inner sep=4.25pt,%tunned
            minimum height=1.5em
        },
        A/.style={
            ->,
            rounded corners,
            line width=0.75pt,
        },
        ArrText/.style={
            font=\sf\scriptsize,
            inner sep=#1
        },
        ALU2/.style={
            muxdemux,
            muxdemux def={
                Lh=7,
                NL=7,
                Rh=2,
                NR=2,
                NB=0,
                NT=0,
                w=3,
                inset w=1,
                inset Lh=2,
                inset Rh=0, 
                square pins=1
            },
            no input leads,%Changed
            circuitikz/muxdemuxes/fill=cyan!30,
        }
        ]
        %Start Drawing the thing.
        \node[N, label=100:\scriptsize MSB,label=70:\scriptsize LSB] at (0,0)(D0){Data 0};%label uses polar coordinates to place text around nodes.
        \foreach \r [count=\t from 0] in {1,...,4}{\node[N,below=0mm of D\t](D\r){Data \r};}
        \node[ALU2, right=4em of D2,scale=0.55](ALU){\huge$\pm$};
        \node[N, below right = 1.5em and 5em of ALU.center](R0){PSW};
        \foreach \r/\d/\b/\c [count=\t from 0] in {
            1/N/31/none,
            2/Z/30/none,
            3/C/29/red!20,
            4/V/28/none,
            5/Q/27/none,
            6/\,/26/none,
            7/XX/25/none,
            8/\,/24/none,
            9/\,/23/none,
            10/\,/\ldots/none,
            11/\,/2/none,
            12/\,/1/none,
            13/\,/0/none%
        }{
            \ifnum \t=0 \xdef\shf{2pt} \else \xdef\shf{0pt} \fi %New conditional variable \shf
            \node[
            right=\shf of R\t,%\shf value is 2p for t=0, and  0pt for t>0
            label=90:\tiny \b,
            minimum height=1.5em,
            minimum width=1em,
            inner sep=2,
            fill=\c
            ](R\r){\d};
        }
        \foreach \k in {1,...,12}{\draw(R\k.north east) -- ++(0,-0.25em);}
        \draw(R1.north west) rectangle (R5.south east);
        \draw(R6.north west) rectangle (R8.south east);
        \draw(R8.north east) -- (R10.100) to [out=-135, in=45] (R10.-100) -| cycle;
        \draw(R13.north east) -- (R10.80) to [out=-135, in=45] (R10.-80) -| cycle;
        \draw[A](ALU.brpin 1) -|  ($(R3.90)+(0,1em)$) node[pos=0.1,above,ArrText=1.5pt]{Carry Out};
        \draw[A]
        (ALU.brpin 2) 
            -|  ++(2em,-2em) node[pos=0.13,above,ArrText=1.5pt]{C}
            |-  ++ (-2em,-3em) -|($(D4.180)+(-2em,0)$) -- (D4);
        \draw[A](D0.0) -| ($(ALU.blpin 2)+(-2.5em,0)$) -- (ALU.blpin 2) node[pos=0.8,above,ArrText=3pt]{A};
        \draw[A](D2.0) -| ($(ALU.blpin 5)+(-2.5em,0)$) -- (ALU.blpin 5) node[pos=0.8,above,ArrText=3pt]{B};
        \draw[A]
        (R3.-90)
            |-  ($(ALU.blpin 7)+(-2em,-1.5em)$)% move the node to the last section 
            |-  (ALU.blpin 7) node[pos=0.6,above,ArrText=3pt]{Carry In};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

It turned out to be a good example to study the behavior of those nodes of the excellent CircuiTikZ package, going to look for what names had been assigned to the pins, and in the elaboration guessing where each one goes if you test consecutively, then discarding the framework that you used to make the registers since you can do the same using positioning by placing nodes next to others using a for statement, the advantage is that it has hidden many points with specific names from where you can place and draw whatever you want.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes,positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        font=\sffamily,
        >={Triangle},
        N/.style={
            draw,
            fill=green!20,
            inner sep=4pt,
            minimum height=1.5em
            },
        A/.style={
                ->,
                rounded corners,
                line width=0.75pt,
            },
        ALU2/.style={
            muxdemux,
            muxdemux def={
                Lh=7,
                NL=7,
                Rh=2,
                NR=2,
                NB=0,
                NT=0,
                w=3,
                inset w=1,
                inset Lh=2,
                inset Rh=0, 
                square pins=1
            },
            draw only left pins={2,5,7},
            circuitikz/muxdemuxes/fill=cyan!30,
        }
    ]
    %Start Drawing the thing.
    \node[N, label=100:\scriptsize MSB,label=70:\scriptsize LSB] at (0,0)(D0){Data 0};%label uses polar coordinates to place text around nodes.
    \foreach \r [count=\t from 0] in {1,...,4}{\node[N,below=0mm of D\t](D\r){Data \r};}
    \node[ALU2, right=4em of D2,scale=0.5](ALU){\huge$\pm$};
    \node[N, below right = 1.5em and 5em of ALU.center](R0){PSW};
    \foreach \r/\d/\b/\c [count=\t from 0] in {
        1/N/31/none,
        2/Z/30/none,
        3/C/29/red!20,
        4/V/28/none,
        5/Q/27/none,
        6/\,/26/none,
        7/XX/25/none,
        8/\,/24/none,
        9/\,/\,/none,
        10/\,/\,/none,
        11/\,/2/none,
        12/\,/1/none,
        13/\,/0/none%
        }{
        \node[
            right=0 of R\t,
            label=90:\tiny \b,
            minimum height=1.5em,
            minimum width=1em,
            inner sep=2,
            fill=\c
        ](R\r){\d};
    }
    \foreach \k in {1,...,12}{\draw(R\k.north east) -- ++(0,-0.25em);}
    \draw(R1.north west) rectangle (R5.south east);
    \draw(R6.north west) rectangle (R8.south east);
    \draw(R8.north east) -- (R10.100) to [out=-135, in=45] (R10.-100) -| cycle;
    \draw(R13.north east) -- (R10.80) to [out=-135, in=45] (R10.-80) -| cycle;
    \draw[A](ALU.rpin 1)+(-0.3em,0) -|  ($(R3.90)+(0,0.75em)$) node[pos=0.07,above,font=\sf\tiny,inner sep=1pt]{Carry Out};
    \draw[A]
        (ALU.rpin 2)+(-0.3em,0)
            -|  ++(2em,-2em) node[pos=0.07,above,font=\sf\tiny,inner sep=1pt]{C}
            |-  ++ (-2em,-3em) -|($(D4.180)+(-2em,0)$) -- (D4);
    \draw[A](D0.0) -- ++(1.5em,0) |- ($(ALU.lpin 2)+(-1em,0)$) -- ($(ALU.lpin 2)+(0.25em,0)$) node[pos=0.8,above,font=\sf\tiny,inner sep=3pt]{A};
    \draw[A](D2.0) -- ++(1.5em,0) |- ($(ALU.lpin 5)+(-1em,0)$) -- ($(ALU.lpin 5)+(0.25em,0)$) node[pos=0.8,above,font=\sf\tiny,inner sep=3pt]{B};
    \draw[A]
        (R3.-90)
            |-  ($(ALU.lpin 7)+(-2em,-1.5em)$) node[pos=0.95,above,font=\sf\tiny,inner sep=1pt]{Carry In}
            |-  ($(ALU.lpin 7)+(0.25em,0)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Brilliant! Circuitikz seems to use a different line width with the muxdemux class, and the arrowheads on the left side are not quite flush with the ALU block. How can this be solved (even if it is more of an aesthetic problem)?

Regards 'carry in' - how to get them above left of the pin, as like A, B?

Just modidy the two last lines:
|-  ($(ALU.lpin 7)+(-2em,-1.5em)$)% move the node to the last section 
|-  ($(ALU.lpin 7)+(0.25em,0)$) node[pos=0.8,above,font=\sf\tiny,inner sep=3pt]{Carry In};

@JLeonV. instead of using the pins and a manually chosen shift for the arrow, you should really not to draw any pin and then using the "border pin" --- for example, ALU.blpin  7 is exactly on the border of the shape. It's on page 184 in the current manual here: https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf. Will add an example on my partial answer.

@Rmano , Thank you very much, I don't know why I ignored that.

This question has too many questions in it, so I suggest splitting it into several. To help a bit, the problem with the ALU shape can be solved using seven pins on the left side and drawing only 3 (to have nice symmetrical pins):
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \tikzset{ALU2/.style={muxdemux,
            muxdemux def={Lh=7, NL=7, Rh=2, NR=1, NB=0, NT=0, w=3,
            inset w=1, inset Lh=2, inset Rh=0, square pins=1},
            draw only left pins={2,5,7},
            circuitikz/muxdemuxes/fill=cyan!30,
    }}
    \draw (0,0) node[ALU2, font=\large\boldmath]{$\pm$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Added later
Notice that if you want to use arrows in the input-output leads, the best approach is not drawing any external pin, and use the border anchors of the shape:

\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Triangle]
    \tikzset{ALU2/.style={muxdemux,
            muxdemux def={Lh=7, NL=7, Rh=2, NR=1, NB=0, NT=0, w=3,
            inset w=1, inset Lh=2, inset Rh=0, square pins=1},
            no input leads,
            circuitikz/muxdemuxes/fill=cyan!30,
    }}
    \draw (0,0) node[ALU2, font=\large\boldmath](A){$\pm$};
    \draw [<-] (A.blpin 2) -- ++(-1,0);
    \draw [<-] (A.blpin 5) -- ++(-1,0);
    \draw [<-] (A.blpin 7) -- ++(-1,0);
    \draw [->] (A.brpin 1) -- ++(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you, that gave me the right hint regards the circuitikz. I wasn't aware about the draw only left pins key.
